# Node js Invalid regular expression: Invalid group

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm using a regular expression to get variable's names out of an Arduino code (C/C++).

The idea is that when it matches a data-type word like 'int' or 'long' or 'String' ecc... I'm able to get the next word which must be the variable name (otherwise you get a compile error).

I'm using this regular expression:

```
/(\bint\b|\blong\b|\bString\b)\s*(?<varName>\w+)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/1923

The problem is that node.js throws this error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(\bint\b|\blong\b|\bString\b)\s*(?<varName>\w+)/: Invalid group
```

and I'm not sure why.
I noticed that on regex101.com using pcre(PHP) it highlights the group, but it is not in javascript.

Anyway I tried to compile that regexp on jsfiddle and it works fine.

I'm using this simple code to check it: (click on jsfiddle link and open console. This code looks awful formatted here but I apparently must paste the code here as well)

https://jsfiddle.net/f9wsu6Lh/7/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to replace variable's names with "[Michael and " + variable's name + "]" in the paragraph below:</p>

<p id="demo">int value1 = 0;
int value2=0;
long longvalue =0;
long verylongvalue=0;</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var var_type = ["long", "String"];
    var var_type2 = "int";
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var regexpString="(\\bint\\b";
    var_type.map(function(type){
        console.log(type);
        regexpString += "\|\\b"+type+"\\b";
    });
    regexpString += ")\\s\*(\?\<varName\>\\w\+)";
    //var original_regexp= "\\b"+var_type2+"\\b\\s\*(\?\<varName\>\\S\+)";
   var regexp = new RegExp(regexpString, 'g');
   var match = regexp.exec(str);
    console.log(match);
    if(match==null){
        console.log('no match found');
    }else{
    var regexp2 = new RegExp("\\b"+match[2]+"\\b", 'g');
    var res2 = str.replace(regexp2, "[Michael and $&]");
   while(match !== null) {
      console.log(match[2]);
      match = regexp.exec(str);
      if(match != null){
        regexp2 = new RegExp("\\b"+match[2]+"\\b", 'g');
        res2 = res2.replace(regexp2, "[Michael and $&]");
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res2;
 }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm stuck. I don't understand where the problem is.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: `(?:\w+)` at the end, note the colons… ??

Comment: @philipp I edited the regular expression part to be included in code tags. Before it wasn't and it wasn't showing the `<varName>` part. My mistake! but in the regex101.com fiddle it's showed properly.

Comment: JavaScript prior to ECMAScript 2018 did not support named capturing groups, use simple numered groups.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right!! That solved the problem! You saved my day!! +1000 points for you! -1000 points for me because I didn't thought about it myself! Thank you very very much!